# Compare 2 dataframes to find common data and extract adjacent data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, datetime

`events` is the dataframe with date as index and looks like this:

```
           co_code
co_stkdate  
2009-03-17  11
2010-02-03  11
2011-02-14  363
2015-01-09  363
2010-10-15  365
```

`residual` is the other dataframe with date as index and contains the elements in co_code of `events` dataframe as the column names. residual looks like this (has more than 700 columns but i've posted 3 for reference):

```
              11    363    365  
co_stkdate
1997-07-02  NaN -12.134525  NaN 
1997-07-04  NaN -3.663248   -15.703843 
1997-07-07  NaN -30.649876  3.400623
1997-07-08  NaN 17.924305   -6.188777
1997-07-10  NaN -25.828099  -0.615380
```

I want to compare the two dataframes to find the common dates for each column of `residual` dataframe individually and extract the specific row and its adjacent rows for each column which has a matching date in `events` dataframe. Since the dataset is very large, I want to iterate through each column of residual to compare the date in accordance with the column name (that matches with the `events` dataframe). Hence, I tried the following code:

```
 orig={}
    extra={}
    #iterating through events index
    for date in events.index:
      #creating index as a new column
      residual['tmp'] = residual.index
      print(type(residual['tmp']))
      date_list = {date}
      #determining the presence of the date in residual index
      if residual['tmp'].isin([date_list]):
        code=events.loc[date, 'co_code']
        #Comparing the co_code
        if code in residual.columns:
          #checks whether the value w.r.t a particular date and co_code as taken from events is present or not
          if pd.notnull(residual.loc[date,code]):
            #Find and add to dictionary top and bottom of values with their dates
            idx=residual.get_loc(residual.loc[date,code])
            extra=residual.iloc[idx-10:idx+10,code]
            orig.update(extra)
      #dropping the new column  
      del residual['tmp']
      #display orig
      orig
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: <class 'set'> is not convertible to datetime
```

The expected output: For example, extract 10 rows (from the `residual` dataframe) above and below the date 2009-03-17 corresponding to 'co_code'=11 (given in `events` dataframe). And expect the output for date 2009-03-17, corresponding to 'co_code'=11 to be:

```
co_stkdate  11
2009-02-25  4.467442
2009-02-26  4.921655
2009-02-27  -4.875917
2009-03-02  1.895546
2009-03-03  -3.162370
2009-03-06  85.396542
2009-03-09  43.233098
2009-03-12  11.389193
2009-03-13  -68.633160
2009-03-16  0.329175
2009-03-17  -0.049623
2009-03-18  3.584602
2009-03-19  -3.602577
2009-03-20  -1.532591
2009-03-23  2.766331
2009-03-24  0.487590
2009-03-25  -3.541044
2009-03-26  -5.055355
2009-03-27  0.887624
2009-03-30  2.530087
```

I want a similar output for all such dates and co_code in `events` dataframe that match with the index and specific column (corresponding to co_code in `events` dataframe) in `residuals` dataframe. How can I remove the error? Any guidance on the best way to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a `merge` job. You provided `events` data, you should provide `residual` and the expected output as well.

Comment: I've edited the post and added residual and expected output aswell. Thanks for pointing it out. You can check out the question for better clarity now.